# Php exec() NOT wait for result, just starting

Tags: php

I use exec to start a job on WINDOWS

```
exec("mycmd.exe $path /lang Eng /out $path /quit");
```

exist a way to just starting process without page hang up for waiting end?
sometimes process take about 2 hours to end...

Comment: You should look into queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead exec, use:

```
pclose(popen("start yourcommand.exe ... ...","r"));
```